# How to execute Javascript before trigger flash click tag

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a flash swf file, which implemented a clicktag function (go to some URL), as I need to record how many user click the flash, so is there any ways to execute a javascript function(record userid) before user was redirect to the destination?

Here the clickTag

```
on (release) {  
    if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {  
        getURL(clickTAG, "_blank");  
    }  
}
```

javascript function look like:

```
function regUserid(ID){  
    $.ajax{  
        url:reg.php,  
        cache: false,  
        type: "GET",  
        data: ID 
    }  
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like now? Can you show some code?

Comment: how are those two connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your AJAX call has some errors in it. It needs to look like:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: reg.php,  
    cache: false,  
    type: "GET",  
    data: ID 
});
```

`(` and `)` needed to be added.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Second, what I would do is send the user to your own website and add a parameter to the url so you can record the url, and in the JavaScript (or even better, your PHP) function, send them off to the correct website.

So something like:

```
on (release) {  
    if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {  
        getURL('http://www.yourownurl.com/reg.php?url=' + clickTAG, "_blank");  
    }  
}
```

And in your `reg.php` you do something to save the `clickTag` and use `header('location:' . $_GET['url'])` to send them to the correct website.

**Update:**

If you want to use `ExternalInterface` you can do the following:

```
on (release) {  
    if (clickTAG.substr(0,5) == "http:") {  
        ExternalInterface.call('regUserid', clickTAG);  
    }  
}
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html
That is assuming you want to send the data to your `regUserid` function. `clickTag` is the parameter in the function `regUserid`.
If you do this you still need to redirect your user to the right website. So something like `document.location.href="http://www.example.com"`.

Comment: thank for you reply, but I am not going to do only 1 function for javascript, I may need to add some more function in the reg(ID), is there any other suggestion? Thank again!

Comment: You could use `ExternalInterface`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, how could I achieve the goal? or any example?

Comment: Great! As I am new to flash action script, your answer is really helpful!!! So could my code like this? -> `ExternalInterface.call('regUserid', clickTag); getURL('http://destination.com',"_blank");`